# Possible complex eigenvectors of all $3 \times 3$ real matrices?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For any $v \in \mathbb {C}^3$, does there exist an $M \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}$ such that:

- $M$ admits no eigenvalue $\lambda$ of multiplicity greater than 1,
- $v$ is an eigenvector of $M$?

It's clear that if $v \in \mathbb{C}^3$ is an eigenvector of $M$, then so is $\overline v$. Any remaining eigenvector must be in $\mathbb {R}^3$.

[edit] *I accidentally typoed earlier, and wrote $\mathbb{C}^{3 \times 3}$ instead of $\mathbb {R}^{3\times 3}$. But that would make the question trivial.*

[edit] *I've now made a change that rules out a trivial yes by ensuring that all eigenvalues have geometric multiplicity at most 1.*

Answer (score 4):

Let $v=v_1+iv_2\neq 0,$ where $v_1,v_2\in \mathbb{R}^3.$ With no loss of generality we may assume that $v_1\neq 0.$

If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent, there is a vector $w\in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $v_1,v_2$ and $w$ form a basis. Let $M$ be defined by $$Mv_1=-v_2,\ Mv_2=v_1, \ Mw=0$$ Then $$Mv=iv, \ M\bar{v}=-i\bar{v},\ Mw=0$$
If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly dependent there are $w_1,w_2\in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $v_1,w_1,w_2$ form a basis (as we have assumed $v_1\neq 0).$ Let $M$ be defined by $$Mv_1=0, \ Mw_1=w_1,\ Mw_2=-w_2$$ Then $Mv=0$ because $v$ is a multiple of $v_1.$

In both cases $M\in \mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}.$

Comment: A slight addendum (to explain away something that confused me): In the second case, the argument can roughly be rephrased as scaling the vector $v$ by a complex number to make it a real vector. Then the aim is just to "find a matrix for which a given real vector is an eigenvector."

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut That's right. If the real and the imaginary part of $v$ are linearly dependent then $v$ is a multiple of one of them, a one which is nonzero.